# Getting property values from random json with nested objects and arrays

Tags: java

Is there a library or a simple recursive way to get all the property values (without property names or json specific characters) from a random json?

For example, from this object:

```
{
    "a": "aVal",
    "b": {
        "b1": "b1Val"
    },
    "c": [
        "cVal", 
        {
            "c1":"c1Val"
        },
        [["c3Val"]]
    ]
}
```

I need the values marked with the `Val` suffix: `aVal, b1Val, cVal, c1Val, c3Val`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library.
pass the JSON string in a constructor and work with objects after that. [Info](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)
Example:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject("{\"a\": \"aVal\",\"b\": {\"b1\": \"b1Val\"},\"c\": [\"cVal\",{\"c1\":\"c1Val\"},[[\"c3Val\"]]]}");
  for (Object objKey : root.names()) {
     //do things here..
  }
```